# Ввод динамического массива через консоль

Tags: c++

Можно узнать как вводить неопределенный массив. То есть массив не имеющий конечный элемент, не имеющий размер.
вот я пробую но ничего:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> myVector;
    int n=1;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=myVector.size(); i++) {
        cin >> i;
        myVector.insert(myVector.end(), i);
    }
    for(i=1; i<=myVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << myVector[i] << " ";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит «ничего»?

Comment: Просто не получаеться вводить неограниченый массив. Пожалуйста поделитесь опытом. И дайте кроме того литературу для изучения олимпиадного программирвания.

Comment: Что конкретно у Вас не получается? В чём выражается проблема?

Comment: Касательно литературы: один вопрос — один ответ, по поводу литературы можно попробовать задать отдельный вопрос, но его скорее всего закроют, т.к. подобные вопросы являются неформатными.

Comment: {vecor<int > myvector;}

Comment: можете написать как можно создать массив неограниченого размера. Проблема в том что немогу создавать такой тип массива.

Comment: а литература просто напишите сайти или ссылки на книги где можно все это изучить

Comment: `std::vector` является динамически-расширяемым массивом, Вы выбрали правильно. Поэтому я и спрашиваю — что не работает? Литературу ищите в гугле.

Comment: можете написать отрывок программы где задается элементы неопределенного массива

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для примера можете использовать следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    int input = 0;
    while(input != 42)
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input != 42)
            myVector.push_back(input);
    }
    std::cout << "The following values were entered: \n";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) 
        std::cout << myVector[i] << " ";
}
```

Цикл ввода работает до тех пор, пока Вы не введёте 42. После этого он выведет все значения, которые предшествовали `42`.

Проблемы в Вашем коде следующие:
`vector myVector;` — во первых std::vector, во-вторых Вы должны указать тип, который содержится в vector. В нашем случае int, поэтому `std::vector<int> myVector;`

`std::` нужно вообще прикреплять к любым стандартным функциям, объектам(смотрите мой код).

Затем, у Вас цикл `for(i=1;i<=myVector.size();i++)`. Во-первых, в C/C++ номерация идёт с нуля, во-вторых, у Вас изначально пустой вектор, поэтому этот цикл ни разу не будет выполнен. Нужно ставить какое-то условие, которое позволит наполнить вектор(в моём коде цикл выполняется до ввода 42 в консоле)

В общем читайте книги, хотя бы простейшие по C++, тогда большинство вопросов отпадут.

Comment: @user5450071, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, нажмите на «галочку» рядом с моим ответом. И впредь всегда принимайте ответы, которые Вас удовлетворяют.